# Creating Single ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, mahapps.metro

I have an existing solution of my WPF UI but it's ViewModel implementation is clunky and I'm looking to improve.

Below is a gif of how my current system works:

- There's a `Current Task` (note: only ever one item)
- There's a `Task List` for Tasks (note: possibly many) that need to run in the future
- When the user selects one list box, the other selection is removed

[image: Two listboxes]

The problem is, I'm implementing `Current Task` as a Listbox with only one item. This means I have to lug around a backing IList for the `ItemSource` and another property for the `SelectedItem`.

**Is there another control I can use to behave like ListBoxItem, but I can bind my CurrentTask directly to it and not have to muck around with an List for `ItemSource` as well?**

**EDIT:** To get the selection to go away when one listbox is selected, I have a trigger set up on the `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: Use TextBlock and bind its Text property.

Comment: @Rohit: OP is asking for a control that implements the "HideSelection" functionality that is native to ListBoxes, ListViews, etc. It's not enough just to show text.

Comment: @RohitVats: Yeah, I'd like to bind it to the whole "TaskDto" object, and merely show the Text in the control using a DataTemplate or something. I thought about just implementing a `ListBoxItem` but got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

(deleted my previous answer)

It occurs to me that at least part of the functionality you're looking for is implemented by the RadioButton class. Multiple RadioButtons in the same scope guarantee that only one of them is selected. You'll probably have to do a little work to make sure that your RadioButtons can be scoped correctly in your UI, and you'll probably need to retemplate some things to get exactly the UI you need. Additionally, RadioButton does not have a SelectedItem/SelectValue property to which it can write to, because WPF provides no built-in mechanism for multiple controls to safely bind to a "SelectedWhatever" property. But you could roll this yourself pretty easily with codebehind or triggers.

Comment: This is an excellent point. I didn't even think about the `RadioButton` control. Groups would allow for it to automatically keep only a single item selected. But I agree, it probably brings with it a fair amount of other changes. Since I'm so close with my current implementation, I probably wont venture this way but it may be good for a future user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the implementation I went with:

**XAML View**

```
<!-- The Current Task box -->
<ListBox x:Name="CurrentTaskBox" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Background="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}">
    <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding CurrentTaskSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding CurrentTask.TaskId}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Selected">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SetTaskDetailsFromCurrentTaskCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>

<!-- The Task List box -->
<ListBox x:Name="TaskListBox" SelectedIndex="{Binding TaskListIndex}" SelectedValue="{Binding TaskListSelection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" DisplayMemberPath="TaskId" Margin="3">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SetTaskDetailsFromTaskListCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TaskListBox}"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
/* Omitted most INPC property declarations...kinda boring */

public ICommand SetTaskDetailsFromCurrentTaskCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(SetTaskDetailsFromCurrentTask); } }
public ICommand SetTaskDetailsFromTaskListCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<TaskScheduleSequenceDto>(async taskSelection => await SetTaskDetailsFromTaskList(taskSelection)); } }


private bool _currentTaskSelected;
public bool CurrentTaskSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _currentTaskSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(() => CurrentTaskSelected, ref _currentTaskSelected, value);
    }
}

private async Task SetTaskDetailsFromTaskList(TaskScheduleSequenceDto taskListSelection)
{
    if (taskListSelection == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var taskDetails = await _broker.RetrieveTaskDetails(taskListSelection.TaskId);

    TaskDetails = taskDetails;
    CurrentTaskSelected = false;
}

private void SetTaskDetailsFromCurrentTask()
{
    TaskDetails = CurrentTask;
    TaskListSelection = null;
    CurrentTaskSelected = true;
}
```

This works fine and only requires that I have a single `CurrentTask` property in my VM, which I think is much cleaner.